# How to dismiss keyboard on iPhone 6 after rotation

Tags: ios, rotation, keyboard, resignfirstresponder

I am trying to dismiss the keyboard when a uisearchdisplaycontroller is no longer active on the iPhone 6 plus. I can end editing of the search bar but the keyboard stays active on the screen. I have tried many ways, but here is my current code.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if(searchDisplayController!.active) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.searchDisplayController!.active = false
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below function for detecting rotation:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
}
```

Also use resignFirstResponder for hiding the keyboard.

Comment: I have tried both of these functions, and resignFirstResponder will not resign upon rotation to landscape on iPhone 6 Plus which is what this is doing as well.

Comment: Is this working on iOS9? I am facing the same problem and this didn't help.